# Почему выводятся "кракозябры" в WebView?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
 wv_scr4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv_scr4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv_scr4.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    wv_scr4.loadData(txtHTML,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать кодировку немного иначе:

```
webView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Все стало видно! Благодарю!